# Capturing View.setOnClickListener() defined through XML

Tags: android, listener, aspectj

I'm using AspectJ with Android and I'm successfully capturing calls to `View.setOnClickListener()` with this aspect:

```
public aspect Test {

    pointcut callPointcut(View view, OnClickListener listener) : call(void View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)) && target(view) && args(listener);

    @SuppressAjWarnings // Exported advice
    before(View view, OnClickListener listener) : callPointcut(view, listener)
    {
        Log.d("AspectJ", "Attempt to set onClick listener on view " + Integer.toHexString(view.getId()));
        Log.d("AspectJ", "Aspect has executed.");
        Log.d("AspectJ", listener.toString());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not capture listeners set up with `android:onClick` in the layout XML. Is there any way to capture this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to do that that way.

If I'm understanding it correctly your listening to calls of setOnClickListener() on Views.

When you set the onclick attribute in xml, its never called. The Listener is set when the View is created - directly. setOnClickListener() is never called.

The only solution would be to check all your views by hand - which is not recommend and probably not what youre looking for.

Comment: I don't mind checking all the Views programatically, but how would I check the listeners? There is no `getOnClickListener()` (but there's a `getOnFocusChangeListener()`... :P)

Comment: Oh wow. I wonder why that is. My bad, I thought there was one. Sorry, can't help you. I'm not familiar with aspectj, I just can tell you that the onclicklistener is directly set when parsing the xml in the constructor of the view (when inflating a layout). You could however parse the xml yourself, then you would atleast get the method name which is called, but no listener object. And it probably is alot of work.

Comment: Yes I thought about parsing the XML. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Weird... According to source code of [`View`] (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java/#3565), `setOnClickListener` is called when the xml attribute is parsed. It is called inside the constructor.

Comment: Interesting, but really not weird, because AspectJ only links on current build, not on Android libraries sadly. I'll try to check a way to link it inside Android library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but why not modify the View class to have an mOnClickListener attribute. Then when the OnClickListener is about to be set in the custom View class, set the attribute to "new OnClickListener(){ ... }" then call setOnClickListener with the attribute. You would then add a public method called getOnClickListener(), which you could call on your custom View object to return said listener.

This may be a roundabout / tedious way, because you would also need to include not only your custom View class, but every subclass of View that you plan on using in your XML and change their superclasses to use your custom View, not Android's. Then, you would need to change your XML elements to reflect that, i.e. com.yourpackage.Button, etc.

Comment: I also thought of this, but way too much work subclassing every View children and also having third-party developer use this classes... The benefit I'm getting from this is way too slim for such a huge effort! Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score -5):

You can use,

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:onClick="testclick"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
```

add following API inside your activity,

```
public void textclick(View v){

//TODO :anything you want 
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with what I'm asking here.